# NetLogo JVM error on Windows ("The JVM could not be started")

Tags: jvm, netlogo

I downloaded and installed NetLogo. Cant run the software after installation. Keep getting the same error message: "The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could block the execution" OS = Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in the NetLogo FAQ at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#windowsmemory.